# why do char takes 2 bytes as it can be stored in one byte

Tags: c#

can anybody tell me that in c# why does char takes two bytes although it can be stored in one byte. Don't you think it is wastage of a memory. if not , then how is extra 1-byte used?
in simple words ..please make me clear what is the use of extra 8-bits.!!

Comment: Ever heard of Unicode?

Comment: Why do we have machines with 4+ gigs of memory, when obviously 640k is good enough for everyone?

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this.  It's a legitimate question.

Comment: +1 Why are people down-voting this, It is a clear enough question and deserves an answer like anything else.

Comment: @Michael, agreed. I see this too often, I'm upvoting to offset it.

Comment: @michael Ames: i agree, it maybe a noobie question but its a valid one and we all were noobies someday :)

Comment: @animesh: just read this and you will understand everything. Very clear and simple explanation of something that people usually think of like a complicated stuff: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: A simple google would have easily provided plenty of answers.

Comment: @AresAvatar, yes, if you know what to search for...

Comment: @Thomas: searching for the exact text of his subject line gave several hits on ASCII vs. UNICODE.

Comment: @AresAvatar, Google will never cease to amaze me then ;)

Answer (score 28):

> although it can be stored in one byte

What makes you think that?

It only takes one byte to represent every character in the English language, but other languages use other characters. Consider the number of different alphabets (Latin, Chinese, Arabic, Cyrillic...), and the number of symbols in each of these alphabets (not only letters or digits, but also punctuation marks and other special symbols)... there are tens of thousands of different symbols in use in the world ! So one byte is never going to be enough to represent them all, that's why the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) standard was created.

Unicode has several representations (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32...). .NET strings use UTF-16, which takes two bytes per character (code points, actually). Of course, two bytes is still not enough to represent all the different symbols in the world; surrogate pairs are used to represent characters above U+FFFF

Answer (score 5):

> The char keyword is used to declare a Unicode character in the range indicated in the following table. Unicode characters are 16-bit characters used to represent most of the known written languages throughout the world.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: `char` represents a UTF-16 code unit, not a single visible glyph (what many refer to as a "character") as one might think.  Sometimes not even a single code point!

Comment: @CoryNelson Can you please expand? If the UTF-16 code point being represented by a specific `char` happens to correspond to the letter 'H', isn't that a single glyph? Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu You have code units (the 16-bit *encoded* values), code points (the 21-bit *decoded* values), and grapheme clusters (*visible* glyphs, including combining characters etc.). Each step is built from one or more of the previous. Some glyphs, like 'H', can be encoded in a single 16-bit code unit -- others, like 'h̨̺̚', are made from several code points.

Comment: @CoryNelson Thank you! I think I understand, plus your response is full of clues for further research.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters.  True, we have enough room in 8bits for the English alphabet, but when it comes to Chinese and such, it takes a lot more characters.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, char's are 16-bit Unicode characters by default.  Unicode supports a much larger character set than can be supported by ASCII.

If memory really is a concern, here is a good discussion on SO regarding how you might work with 8-bit chars: [Is there a string type with 8 BIT chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916838/is-there-a-string-type-with-8-bit-chars)

References:

On C#'s char datatype:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay(v=vs.80).aspx

On Unicode:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Answer (score -2):

because utf-8 was probably still too young for microsoft to consider using it

Comment: I doubt it. UTF-8 is more compact, but the fact that it has variable size characters makes it less efficient for string manipulations.